# Can we interchange the for loop parameters in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax, evaluation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char i=250;
    for(i<0;i++;i=0,printf("%d", i));
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, the output is 0. From what i understand is, a for loop should have the first parameter as initialisation, then condition, then increment. But in this question the initialisation is happening at the last and still the code is giving valid result. Can someone explain how?

Comment: Your code makes not much sense. The initialization step (`i<0`) is a logical comparison, the result of which is discarded. The loop condition `i++` will evaluate to true as long as `i` is not zero, and if you set `i` to zero at the increment step, then it's hardly surprising that it prints out zero.

Comment: The answer to the title - no, you can't.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Clearly you can, as someone has done so.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The question implies "..without consequences" or "..without changing the behavior".  But you can nitpick of course.

Comment: @r3mainer for sure that code is not the perfect example of a 'readable' code, but without UB it has sense no ? ^^

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, humans often speak or write with implied context. That is not a good way to proceed in technical documentation, as humans come from many cultures, contexts, and stages of life and learning and hence may not share your particular context, and especially where computers are involved, as the computers are mechanical and care nothing for your context. Practitioners in such fields should acquire habits of being precise.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree. The "without consequences" is very obviously implied here.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? Is this real code?

Comment: @jarmod yes it was a practice question from a C programming book

Answer (score 6):

The clauses or expressions in a `for` statement are always interpreted based on where they are (first, second, or third) in the `for` statement. In this code:

```
char i=250;
for(i<0;i++;i=0,printf("%d", i));
return 0;
```

- `i` is set to either 250 (if `char` is unsigned) or −6 (if `char` is signed, eight-bit, and typical two’s complement wrapping is used for the conversion from 250 to `char`). (The C standard permits other possibilities, but they are unusual and are not discussed further in this answer.)
- To start the loop, the initial clause `i<0` is evaluated. Its result is inconsequential because it is ignored.
- To decide whether the loop ends, the test clause `i++` is evaluated. This produces either 250 or −6, per the above, and, separately, increments `i` to either 251 or −5. In either case, the result of the expression is non-zero, so the loop continues.
- The body of the loop, `;` is evaluated. Since this is an empty statement, it has no effect.
- The post-iteration clause, `i=0,printf("%d", i)` is evaluated. This sets `i` to 0 and prints `i`, resulting in output of “0”.
- The test clause `i++` is evaluated again. Since `i` is zero, this produces 0, and, separately, increments `i` to 1. Since the result of the expression is zero, the loop terminates.
- `return 0;` is executed, cause the program to end with a success status.

Answer (score 4):

Actually for loop works in the following way:

```c
for (step 0; step 1; step 3) {
    step 2;
}
```

Here, **step 0** is executed only once. Then **step 1 -> step 2 -> step 3 -> step 1** and the loop goes on.

> *a for loop should have the first parameter as initialisation, then condition, then increment.*

this is more like a convention. And explaining the for loop in this way makes perfect sense (especially because in step 1, the program executes the statement and continues to step 2 only when it returns true). And so we utilize for loop in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer to your question "Can we interchange the for loop parameters in C?" is: **No** .

This code, if not meant to confuse the reader, must be a badly written one.

*Walk-through*

1. `i` is initialized with a value 250
2. `i<0` as the initialization step is ignored
3. `i++` is executed, since the old `i` is not `0`, the loop continues
4. nothing in the loop body
5. set `i=0` and print its value `0` out
6. come back to the `i++`, noting that the previous `i` value is zero, so loop stops

Answer (score 2):

> "*Can we interchange the `for` loop parameters in C?*"

We can interchange the expressions itself (for whatever reason, for example as experiment because it usually makes no sense to do so), but we can't change the syntax (how an expression is evaluated at a certain place).

A `for` loop has a fixed syntax following conventionally the form:

```
for (initializations; condition; in-/decrements)
```

You can use expressions where you want to but it has quite different effects.

If you place for example the initialization expressions at the second place they are used as condition.

Same goes if you would take the in-/decrements and place them at the second place. Then they would be evaluated as condition, too.

Equivalently, if you would place the expression used as condition at the first or third place, this expression will not be used as the condition anymore.

That's what the C standard says to this topic:

> 6.8.5.3    The for statement
>
> 1 The statement
>
> ```
> for (clause-1; expression-2; expression-3) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. Ifclause-1is a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.161)
>
> 2 Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted.  An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a non zero constant.
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.8.5.3

Answer (score 1):

A for loop `for(init; cond; inc) { body }` Is basically executed like this:

```
init;
while(cond) {
    body;
    inc;
}
```

For some cases it is possible to switch things, but in the general case it is not.